# Why HTTP protocol specifies that GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval?

Tags: http, https

In the [HTTP 1.1 protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) there is a part mentioning safe methods:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
> HEAD methods **SHOULD NOT** have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
> This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
> and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
> fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

However, it is not particularly clear what can go wrong that we need to keep GET and HEAD safe. I can only think of cache servers and proxies in between, but that is not the case on HTTPS which is used in most of the cases.

Baseically the question is what can go wrong if someone changes something or even save something in DB on a GET request?

Comment: Prefetch. Crawlers. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Baseically the question is what can go wrong if someone changes something or even save something in DB on a GET request?

Assume that your server changes your data on GET request like:

`GET /transferfund?to={account_number}&amount={amount_to_transfer}`

A potential attacker can ask you vising the site where there would be the image like this `<img src="http://yourbank.com/transferfund?to=ATTACKER_ACCOUNT&amount=USD100000">`. Having your session cookie preserved in your browser visiting that page would make a GET request to image source which will lead to money leakage.